# Combine PDF files in a loop ( Hummus-Recipe )

Tags: node.js, pdf, hummus.js

I work with Hummus-Recipe library and it's work fine but I want to make a function that accept array of files to append all files to one.

This is my code that work:

```
const filesRoot = './uploads';
router.route('/')
.get( async (request, response) => {
        const src =  filesRoot + '/one.pdf';
        const appendedFile = filesRoot + '/two.pdf';
        const appendedFile2 = filesRoot + '/three.pdf';
        const output = filesRoot + '/new.pdf';
        const recipe = new HummusRecipe(src, output);
        recipe
            .appendPage(appendedFile)
            .appendPage(appendedFile2)
            .endPDF();
    });
```

How can I take this code and make it accept array??

Something like that:

```
let combinePdfFiles = (array) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    }

};
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [easy-pdf-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easy-pdf-merge) package that let you merge an array of some pdf files.

Usage:

```
const merge = require('easy-pdf-merge');

merge(source_files,dest_file_path,function(err){
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
  console.log('Success')
});
```

Example:

```
merge(['File One.pdf', 'File Two.pdf'], 'File Ouput.pdf', function(err){
  if(err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
  console.log('Successfully merged!')
});
```

Comment: Hey, I try to use this library on my MacBook and I got error that I need to install java ? :/

Comment: @WebDeveloper there is no need to install java. It is just javascript library.

Comment: I got this error: To use the "java" command-line tool you need to install a JDK

Comment: @WebDeveloper Did you use ```npm i easy-pdf-merge``` command?

Comment: Yes is in my package.json: "dependencies": {
    "easy-pdf-merge": "^0.2.2",

Comment: @WebDeveloper I think problem is with your terminal. Try to fix it first.

Answer (score 0):

I create this function and it work.

```
const combinePdfFiles = async (files, companyID, flowID) => {
    const filesRoot = `./uploads/${companyID}/${flowID}`;
      try {
        const originalFile = `${filesRoot}/${files[0]}`;
        const output = `${filesRoot}/combined.pdf`;
        const recipe = new HummusRecipe(originalFile, output);
        for (let i = 1; i < files.length; i++) {
            recipe
            .appendPage(`${filesRoot}/${files[i]}`);
        }
        recipe.endPDF();
      } catch (error) {
          throw error;
      }

};
```